# jQuery mouse down and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a requirement hot select hotspot question type admin with in the image we need to capture that hot spot location.in user side based on click we need to find out user click valid or not . I am getting positions but I am facing problem hotspot re-size on mouse down can any one help me for the task .. mouse down and re-sizable  at a time problem

find the link

http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/Ju5cA/1/

Just check the fiddle link browse one image in that image click any position and drag once. Means selecting some portion. When I tried mouse click+drag it it not resizing and when I click once and after I try to re size it is working fine. I want on click+re size at a time

```
var $hotspot = $('<div id="hotspot_' + spotCount + '"></div>').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'display': 'block',
    'left': (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) - (e.data.x / 2),
    'top': (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) - (e.data.y / 2),
    'height': e.data.y,
    'width': e.data.x,
    'background': 'url(' + config.icon + ')',
    'cursor': 'pointer'
}).resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w, se, sw, nw, ne"
}, {
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});
simulateHandleClick($hotspot, 's', e.pageX, e.pageY);
$hotspot.draggable();

$imageContainer.append($hotspot);


$hotspots = $hotspots.add($hotspot);

$hotspot.on('click', initSpotConfig);
}



var simulateHandleClick = function (item, handle, x, y) {

    item.find('.ui-resizable-' + handle).trigger({
        type: 'mousedown',
        which: 1,
        pageX: x,
        pageY: y
    })
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the wording of your question?

Comment: just check the fiddle link   browse one image in that image click any position and drag once. means selecting  some portion .when i tried mouse click+drag it it not resizing and when i click once and after i try to re size it is working fine. i want on click+re size at a time